# Process substitution with heredoc works in zsh. How to make it work in bash?

Tags: bash, zsh, heredoc, process-substitution

I want the ability to pass a heredoc to the `source` command for local interpretation.
The body of the heredoc document will be injected later before calling the script, and can be multiline.

I came up with this trick, which works in `zsh`:

```
source <(<<'heredoc'
echo foo
sleep 10
echo done
heredoc
) && echo ok || echo no
```

it prints `foo`, sleeps 10 seconds, then prints `done`, then `ok`. So far, so good.

Now, the script needs to run in `bash`.
When I feed `bash` (or `sh`) the exact same thing, I only get `ok`, with no wait at all, as if the command I was providing with the heredoc was just `true`.

I cannot understand why, and how I can build the same behavior in `bash` and `sh`.

Comment: Can't you do the same thing with `eval`?

Comment: `pass a heredoc to the source` You want _specifically_ the ability to pass heredoc to the `source` command (why?), _or_ do you want to execute text coming from standard input or some text stored inside a variable? Is this XY question?

Comment: Isn't this the same as just putting the heredoc contents as top-level commands in the script?

Comment: @Barmar, using `eval` in place of `source, I get `zsh: permission denied: /proc/self/fd/14`. Similar behavior in `bash`.
Yes, it is the same as putting the heredoc contents as top-level commands, but I do need to inject a string unescaped (that's why the heredoc and the single quotes in its delimiter)

Comment: @KamilCuk I want to merge text unescaped coming from an external source. More specifically, a multi-line script that represents a valid bash fragment, which needs to be included unescaped into a for loop. It is going to be used for a GitHub Action

Comment: I don't think this is related to source. `bash` doesn't understand `<(<<'heredoc'`. Use `<(cat <<'heredoc'`

Comment: @Barmar with your solution I get `bash: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied`

Comment: It works for me in bash 5.1.4. It doesn't work in bash 3.2.57, but there's no error.

Comment: At least for sh, the answer is easy: `sh` (POSIX shell, or old Bourne shell) does not have process substitiution. If your `sh` is symlinked to another shell, the outcome depends on to what extent that shell tries to achieve POSIX compatibility. As for bash, the behaviour could be version dependent. What do you see, when you do a `echo $BASH_VERSION`?

Comment: @user1934428 5.2.21(1)-release

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to make it work in bash?

Remove any here documents and execute the commands. You could preserve the group.

```
{
   echo foo
   sleep 10
   echo done
} && echo ok || echo no
```

You can use, both in zsh and bash, `source /dev/stdin` if you want to execute commands in the current execution environment coming from a steam, like a here document. No need for `<(` process substitution in either case. So here you go:

```
source /dev/stdin <<heredoc
echo foo
sleep 10
echo done
heredoc
```

Note: this looks very odd thing to do and most probably there are better solutions to what you are doing.

> why

Because in bash empty redirection like a here document without a command does nothing. You have to for example `cat` the content of the stream created by here document to output it to standard output for process substation to capture it.

Comment: Seems like he was assuming that `<(<<heredoc` would work analogously to `$(<<filename)`, which automatically treats it like `$(cat filename)`. But that's a special case, not something that generalizes.

Answer (score 2):

Redirections in bash aren't processes, so it doesn't make sense to use a *process* substitution to capture them. But you can certainly do it if you use a process to capture the redirection. `cat` does that.

The following works in bash 4 and up:

```
source <(cat <<'heredoc'
echo foo
sleep 10
echo done
heredoc
) && echo ok || echo no
```

You [cannot source a process substitution in bash 3](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2006-01/msg00018.html).

Comment: @pjh I haven't been able to reproduce that using either macOS bash or docker bash 3.

Comment: kojiro, you are correct.  I just checked that it ran, not that it produced the correct output.  Duh!  It definitely doesn't work on Bash 3.2 either.  Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `eval` ("evil"); in this context, it's likely not a security issue.

```bash
eval '
echo foo
sleep 10
echo done
' && echo ok || echo no
```

You could also just, you know, not use dynamic code execution:

```bash
{
    echo foo
    sleep 10
    echo done
} && echo ok || echo no
```

Comment: the former is not okay, as the injected string may contain single quotes that need to be preserved. The latter seems to work well, though